# Save and load autogenerated column visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid and a column-selection-dialog in WPF:

```
<DataGrid Margin="10,10,10,5" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" IsReadOnly="True" />
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="{Binding ContextMargin}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DGrid, Path=Columns}" Background="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToBoolConv}}" Margin="5,3,5,3" Content="{Binding Header}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Border>
```

That works fine.
My problem is now:
How do I get the columns, that are (in)visible in my grid to save them and after the next start of my application load this settings again?
I thought I have to bind the column visibility to any variable, but I don't know how I should do that because I don't know how the columns of the datagrid are named. That is a dynamic value. Has anyone any idea how do I can solve this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you doing it in `DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn`?

Comment: Hi Omribitan, thanks for the hint ;) It was late yesterday :)
I added the Check/Uncheck-Event to the Checkbox to get any changes and set this visibility in DataGrid_AutogeneratingColumn.